# Passing function with default parameter value as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am a bit puzzled with the following behavior. I pass a function with two parameter, one having a default value, as a template parameter and call the function with one argument. Why does it fail to compile? And, what is the solution/workaround?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename Function> 
void eval(Function function) {
    function(10);
}

void sum(int i, int j = 0) {
    cout << "Sum is " << i + j;
}

int main() {
    sum(10);    // OK, of course :)
    eval(sum);  // Error!
}
```

Note that this question is not about calling a templated function with default parameter.

The error message:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void eval(Function) [with Function = void (*)(int, int)]':
prog.cpp:15:10:   required from here
prog.cpp:6:10: error: too few arguments to function
  function(10);
          ^
```

Comment: It would help if you also provide the error message.

Comment: @perreal No! That's about a templated function with default parameter. My question is about passing a function with default parameter as a template parameter to another function.

Comment: @EissaN. you mean a 'function', not a 'templated function'. `sum` is not a template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the optional parameter is part of function declaration. When you call using a function pointer, essentially all the compiler knows is the type of the function pointer. So this line `function(10)` roughly translates to:

```
void (*)(int, int) sm = function; // the equivalent happens at the type deduction step 
sm(10); // whoops, where is the second int
```

The compiler will need the second argument because it has no way of knowing whether `sm` is pointing to `sum` which has a default argument, or some other `void foo(int a, int b)` which doesn't have a default argument.

Answer (score 4):

This is why function pointers are weak. You got two good answers of *why* this doesn't work - the function template doesn't know your function has a defaulted argument.

The solution is to not pass a function pointer - pass in a function object. In this case, you can handwrite a lambda:

```
 eval([](int i){ return sum(i); });
```

which seems like a really annoyingly verbose way of basically just writing `sum` in a way that actually works. But this sort of thing comes up periodically (what if `sum` were an overloaded name?) so it's handy to just have a lambdafying macro around (C++14 required):

```
#define AS_LAMBDA(func) [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { \
   return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

so you can write:

```
eval(AS_LAMBDA(sum));
```

That will work with defaulted arguments, overloaded names, and even work to bind member functions:

```
struct X {
    int i;
    int add(int j) { return i + j; }
};

X x{42};
eval(AS_LAMBDA(x.add));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `sum`:

```
sum(10);
```

compiler translates it to:

```
sum(10, 0);
```

There is no error, as arguments are matched. For the compiler there exist no `sum` taking one argument. You can say a *pre-compiler* doing the magic of passing `0` to second argument to `sum`. With templates this magical *pre-compiler* doesn't exist, and the actual compiler matches `sum` with two strictly two arguments, which it doesn't find, and hence the error.

Just like

```
void foo(int);
void foo(float);
```

will fail to compile with `foo(10.2);` where argument `double` can be changed to either `float` or `int`. The compiler will not *assume*  `float` for you. Similarly, compiler will not try to find best match of `sum` just for the sake of successful compilation.

Comment: "magic" aside, it would be more correct to say that the default parameter isn't part of the type definition of the function. Which is all the template can see.

Comment: Is there a way to work around this? In c++14, I think you could wrap up `sum` inside a variadic lambda I think. `eval( [](auto...args){ return sum(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);});`