# Call with minimal number of argument from lambda with default arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, default-arguments

For the purpose of a library I am currently writing, my goal is, given lambda function specified by the user, to call it internally with arguments of my choice.

So far it works properly and looks like this:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<typename T> struct GetFinfos;

template<typename R, typename F, typename ...Args>
struct GetFinfos<R(F::*)(Args...) const> {
    static std::tuple<Args...> createChosenTuple() {
        return std::make_tuple(Args(1)...);
    }   
};

template<typename F>
void internal_lambda_call(const F & f) {
//let's suppose for convenience that we have a working call_from_tuple in C++14
    std::apply(f,  GetFinfos<decltype(&F::operator())>::createChosenTuple() );
}

int main()
{
    auto f = [](int i, int j, int k) { };

    internal_lambda_call(f); // calls f(1,1,1);
}
```

Now, `C++14` introduced lambda functions with default arguments and I wonder if the library could use this extra bit of information from the user.

```cpp
auto g = [](int i, int j = 5, int k = 5) { };
```

As I understand, lambdas with default parameters still have only one `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()` operator. Therefore the `GetFinfos` is blind to the default parameters and `internal_lambda_call(g)` calls `g(1,1,1)`.

However, since we have access to the full argument types list, we could theoretically try to call the lambda with a decreasing number of arguments and pick the last valid one.

```cpp
g(1,1,1)  //valid call
g(1,1)    //valid call
g(1);     //valid call   <---- last valid one 
g();      //invalid call
```

So my question is: if there is any existing machinery so `internal_lambda_call(g)` calls automatically either `g(1)` or `g(1,5,5)`? I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37325809/4953963) that generic lambdas can be used to wrap the lambda and make it work with an explicit number of argument. But I don't see a way to get this minimal number of argument automatically.

Comment: Note that this code fails for functors with overloaded or templated `operator()`.

Comment: And yes, there should be a way to do this, but there is no simple "existing machinery" for it - the only way I can think of has a lot of ugly SFINAE. I hope someone shows up with an elegant implementation but that might not be in store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see a way to get this minimal number of argument automatically.

Maybe... with a little of recursion and SFINAE ...

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gmna_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> is, int)
   -> decltype( (void)std::declval<F>()
                   (std::declval<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>>()...),
                std::size_t{} )
 { return sizeof...(Is); }

template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gmna_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>, long)
 { return gmna_helper<F, T>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)+1u>{}, 0); }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t getMinNumArgs ()
 { return gmna_helper<F, std::tuple<Ts...>>(std::index_sequence<>{}, 0); }

int main ()
 {
   auto g = [](int, int = 5, int = 5) { };

   constexpr auto n = getMinNumArgs<decltype(g), int, int, int>();

   static_assert( n == 1, "!" );
 }
```

As the same OP say in a comment, the difference in the signature between the two `gmna_helper()`, the `int` vs the `long` argument, is to introduce a ordering: the function is called with a `int` so the version receiving exactly an `int` is selected, when available. That is: is selected when a functional of type `F` is callable whith only the first `sizeof...(Is)` arguments.

Otherwise, when the `int` version isn't available (SFINAE disabled through the failure in the call inside the `decltype()`) the `long` (ever available) is selected.

Comment: For 100% safety you should probably interleave a `void` in the comma operators there (in case the functor returns something with `operator,` overloaded).

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Never underestimate the power of comma operator. Good point. Thanks.

Comment: Nicely done ! Could you comment a little bit on the choice for `int` and `long` ? I just understand that the dummy parameters are needed to disambiguate between the two overloads while introducing some ordering.

Comment: @yultan - You understand the important point: `int` vs `long` is exactly to disambiguate and give the precedence to the `int` version. Answer improved.